# When I should load a new access token?

Tags: facebook, cookies, oauth-2.0

My app uses Facebook Javascript SDK authorization on client side, and for authorized user app fetches access token from Facebook API, using facebook cookie with signed request and provided `code`, and store it into database.

Everything is working fine, but i'm wondering, when I should refresh stored access token? What if user have changes password, and have signed in/connected again.

As I understand, now she has new access token, and app should load it from Facebook. But how I can understand when I should check for a new token? Check on each request with facebook cookie doesn't work, because it's few request per second for each user (event if she didn't change a password). Or maybe i'm doing something wrong?

I mean:

- I've authorized user on client side
- I've cookie with signed request
- Signed request is pretty enough to authorize user on server side (validate user credentials)
- I can get `access token` by calling Facebook API, anytime when user user makes request to my app (because I need a `code` from signed request). So, i'm doing it when I don't have stored `access token` or existing `access token` has expired.
- `access token` just stored in database, and can be used anytime, in different thread, maybe few minutes later (mean we don't have user request and cookie with signed request)
- What if stored `access token` not expired, but invalidated on facebook side? I need to fetch new `access token`, but cookie has gone at this moment.

Currently I see only one way: store `code` from signed request into databse, and when we have found that we have invalid `access token`, try to load it. But i'm note sure that it's proper way, and not so much usable for most cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have client token and server token, the client one is short lived (a few hours) and the server one is long lived (60 days).

The token on the client side should not bother you too much since you can get a new one easily as it states in the "[Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/)" guide:

> **Desktop Web and Mobile Web apps which implement authentication with the Javascript SDK**
>
> Calling FB.getLoginStatus() or ensuring status: true is set when you
>   call FB.init() means that the next time a user lands on your
>   application and is signed into Facebook, the authResponse object you
>   are passed as a result of those calls will contain a fresh, valid
>   access token.
>
> In this case, its simply the act of the user using your application
>   which implicitly generates a new access token.

The token on the server side, which you persist in the db, can not be as easily reproduced, the user has to be sent to the auth dialog again:

> **Desktop Web and Mobile Web apps which implement the server-side authentication flow**
>
> To obtain a fresh access token in this case you must pass the user
>   through the full server-side flow again: i.e. obtain a code and
>   exchange it for a new access token.
>
> However, assuming the user has not de-authorized your application,
>   when you redirect the user into the OAuth Dialog, the user will not be
>   prompted to reauthorize your application, and will be immediately
>   redirected to your redirect_uri. This means that the re-authentication
>   process can appear transparent to the user.

You can of course send a client token to the server and persist that, but it's pretty pointless since it's short lived.
Another option is to use the [new endpoint to extend](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) a **valid** client token on the server side and then persisting that.

As for "how to know when do get a new token", on the server side when you are making api requests just check the response and see if an error returned and if so what it is (there's a list in the first url I added).
If the token has expired then just send the user to the auth dialog again (you can return some kind of code to the client side and do it from there) and then save the new token to the db.

There's no need to check cookies, those are used in the background but you should not have anything to do with them.

---

## Edit

Don't use the cookies, they should not concern you at any time.

What you should do:

On the server side you should follow the instructions in the [Server-Side auth guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/), get the "code" and exchange it with a token.
That token will have 60 days.

Use that token, which you store in your db, as needed (other threads, what not) and when you are getting an error back from facebook saying that the token has expires just navigate the user back to the auth dialog page.

You can not use the "code" to get more than one token so that won't help you.
If the user session (and token) got invalidated (for various reasons) you will still get an error back from facebook when trying to make an api request, when that happens just send the user to the auth dialog again.

Comment: Does it means that there is no way to combine client side Javascript authentication with server side authentication? I mean that it's curently enought for server to parse Facebook cookie to authorize user on server side. But this cookie doesn't contains access token, and server don't know is currenlty stored access token still valid, or not.

Comment: There's no reason for you to get involved with the cookie, let the SDKs do that for you. With every token comes the expiration time (except for app tokens) and you can check against that to see if the token is still valid, and if so how long does it have. As for js/server auth, as I wrote you can send a client token to the server but it's pointless, unless you extend it.

Comment: Seems that we're talking about different things. I've updated my question, can you take a look, please?

Comment: What what benefits of using only server-side auth? I still have same problem (with invalid token in different thread), but it requires writing a lot of code (because I need client side flow - button, auth popup, client side validation and page refresh, etc. It will really user unfriendly to make this with my own way, instead of standard facebook's UI)

Comment: The server side auth results in a token for 60 days, the client side flow token is for a few hours, if that's enough for you then use that. To get the server side you can't use the auth popup, you'll have to redirect the user to the auth dialog page.

Comment: I mean that before redirecting I should place Facebook connect button, make some JS to create new popup when user click, etc.

Comment: No, all you need to do is: `top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?....."`, no button, no pop-up.

Comment: But I should have same Facebook Authentication flow as all other sites (all other sited have facebook button and popup with authorization). Users are expecting standard way of facebook authrization

Comment: anyway, I don't see any benefits, exacly same problems with access token

Comment: No, not all sites have that, it's just the client side auth, since facebook have a server side auth flow as well it is considered "standard". Anyway, you can try and reinvent the wheel or what ever you're trying to do, or you can follow the **official** documentation/guides. It's up to you.

Comment: I'm folowing official documentation, using already implemented official SDK (instead of implementing own whenl, as you're suggesting), and it's working already

Comment: I never suggested implementing your own SDK, but if you follow the official guide please tell me where in the server side auth flow do they even mention "cookie"? They don't.

Comment: But what the reason? Ok, forgot 'client side auth' and 'server side auth', it's 'app auth', doens't matter what language i'm using, and where. Server-side auth is good fit only when you have limited by browser. When you modern browser, that supports JavaScript, it's much easier to use Facebook JavaScript SDK. Anyway, we're talking about different things, i'm asking about handling invalid access token (doesn't matter how i've got it), not about how I can get it (i know how). By using raw server side auth, I still have such problem

Comment: I'm sorry but you're just wrong. Server side token good for 60 days, client side is good for a few hours, obviously that's not the same. The link I gave you that is titled [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/) is the **OFFICIAL** documentation about exactly what you're asking, what else do you need?

Comment: Thanks, I just found this link too (as I see there is no official solution). And I don't care about expiration time at this moment, i didn't mention it anywhere, why you've metioned it, is it an important difference within my question?

Comment: I gave you a link to this document in the first answer, so if you just found this link then you just haven't read my answer. As for the expiration time, firstly it shows that in fact there's a difference between server and client auth, not as you said "app auth". Secondly, in your question you were saying something about other threads and things like that, and so I assumed that you need extra processing time, since client tokens are really short they just not fit for that.

Comment: Oh, really, seems that I've missed this link in your answer, sorry.